# Const references - C++

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I had a doubt regarding the concept of const references in C++.

```
int i =10;   
const int &j = i;  
cout<<"i="<<i<<" j:"<<j; // prints i:10 j:10

i = 20;
cout<<"i="<<i<<" j:"<<j;  // prints i:20 j:10
```

Why second `j` statement doesn't print the new value i.e `20`.

How it is possible if references to any variable denotes strong bonding between both of them.

Comment: Prints 20 20 on gcc 4.5.2, what compiler are you using?

Comment: That is wrong.  http://ideone.com/IATb1  What compiler are you using.

Comment: What compiler did you try out this code with?  This shouldn't be correct, and, as expected, I can't reproduce it with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Is it the only code or did you cut this out of a bigger context? If so: could it be that in the bigger context one of your variables is shadowed by a local?

Comment: I can't imagine a compiler existing that would make such a trivial mistake.

Answer (score 6):

That is a compiler bug. The code should print `20 20`.

Comment: I would not call this a compiler bug because it is so basic it is a complete fail. Also because it completely contradicts the specs.

Comment: so it's not a bug if it completely contradicts the specs?

Comment: It is too early to call this a bug, There is not a piece of code that can reproduce the affect as yet. It is much more likely that the above is a user error and they have snipped out the relevant piece of context that allows us to diagnose their mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason why `j` wouldn't print `20` in the second `cout`.

I ran this code :

```
int main() {
        int i =10;   
        const int &j = i;  
        cout<<"i="<<i<<" j:"<<j << endl; // prints i:10 j:10

        i = 20;
        cout<<"i="<<i<<" j:"<<j << endl;  // prints i:20 j:10 
        return 0;
}
```

And it gave me this output:

```
i=10 j:10
i=20 j:20
```

See the online demo yourself : http://ideone.com/ELbNa

That means, either the compiler you're working with has bug (which is less likely the case, for its the most basic thing in C++), or you've not seen the output correctly (which is most likely the case).

Answer (score 3):

**const reference** means it cannot change the value of the refferant. However, referrant can change it's value which in turn affects the reference. I don't know why you are getting the output you shown.

[It actually changes and see the output here.](http://ideone.com/EdEh2)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one more point here, `const` reference doesn't require lvalue to initialize it. For example

```
int &r = 10;            //ERROR: lvalue required
const int &cr = 10;     //OK
```